# Can every activity/node be wait by calling waitForSignal() in jBPM?

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn, jpdl

I noticed that in jPDL(in classic jBPM4.0), there are a function named: waitForSignal()

and also a type of activity/node named **state**. the state activity/node will make the engine waiting.

so, my question is can activity/node be set to wait by calling this method (in for example the enter actity/node event handler) ?